# Python server is messing up string and float in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pythonanywhere

I'm ingesting data with python to aws elasticsearch. The python script is running on pythonanywhere.com. The original data source is a csv file. 
One column is causing problems on the server:
df.TotalCosts:

```
0        3,56
1        0,00
2        6,32
3        2,37
4        0,00
```

When doing this operation: `df['net'] = df.TotalCosts*0.19`:

I get:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

I replace the decimal separator: `df['TotalCosts'] = [x.replace(',', '.') for x in df['TotalCosts']]`

The data is ingested, but the code doesn't execute until the end, and I get:

```
    raise AttributeError("Can only use .str accessor with string values!")
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!
```

I also tried this:

```
    df['TotalCosts'] = [x.replace(',', '.') for x in df['TotalCosts']]
    df['TotalCosts'] = df['TotalCosts'].astype(float)
```

then the server tells me :

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

So if you keep TotalCosts as it is, it's treated as a string, if you want to convert it, it's suddenly a float?? dtypes says it's an object. 
Btw, the script works when I ingest from VS Code, the problems are only the python server. What could be the problem?

Comment: `df['TotalCosts'] = df['TotalCosts'].str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)`

Comment: You might have an issue with the following if your float values are > 1k: Your floats may be represented as : 1,000.15 OR 1.000,15 depending on the formatting. I would suggest to simply reformat the string into a float using a lambda function which might be throwing the errors for your attempted fixes.

Comment: `df['TotalCosts'] = df['TotalCosts'].str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)`= `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!`

Comment: Maybe you have a mixture of floats and strings in that dataframe due to some kind of parsing weirdness?  You could try something like `df['TotalCosts'] = [(x.replace(',', '.') if type(x) == str else x) for x in df['TotalCosts']]`

Comment: @GilesThomas unfortunately it causes the same error: `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'`

Comment: Which line does that error come from?  And is there any more in the error traceback?